# How many arguments are in `ls -isw 40 /usr`?

Tags: shell, arguments

How many arguments are in this command line?

```
[me@localhost]$ ls -isw 40 /usr
```

Some say just one, the `/usr` because `40` is the argument to the `w` switch
not the command and some say two, because everything but the command and the switches is considered an argument and it doesn't make sense to ask
"argument to the command" or "argument to the switch".

which one is correct ?

Comment: Does it matter? Nobody defines "the number of argument of a command", because defining this wouldn't be useful to anything

Comment: It was a question in my exam and that's why I asked it ...

Comment: We don't do homework for people. Especially when such stupid homework and the student tell us he wants to cheat.

Comment: Asking about something you saw in an exam you've already done isn't cheating.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 I don't believe that homework questions are off topic (there's a meta on this somewhere),. Personally either I skip them or  I give pointers rather than a solution, because i think it's important for the OP to learn rather than copy. This here seems to be a learning question.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 The POSIX standard defines what an argument is and therefore also how many there are in any given command line. It is useful to know how many arguments there are if one tries to validate a set of them in some script or program. The question is neither stupid nor an attempt at cheating, as far as I'm aware. Homework/exam questions are welcome here if they are advertised as such (the user here did so in comments). People are free to avoid them, or to answer them, but please don't leave snarky comments.

Answer (score 8):

There are three arguments: `-isw`, `40`, and `/usr`.

When parsing the command line arguments, the GNU `ls` utility will see three *options*: `-i`, `-s`, and `-w`

The `40` is an *option argument* to the `-w` option.

The `/usr` at the end is an *operand* (neither an option nor an option argument).

An argument is

> In the shell command language, a parameter passed to a utility as the equivalent of a single string in the `argv` array created by one of the `exec` functions. An argument is one of the options, option-arguments, or operands following the command name.

This is what tells us `ls -isv 40 /usr` is a command with three argument. If `ls` was a shell script that we had written ourselves, then the value of the special variable `$#` in that script would have been `3` when the script is called in that specific way.

An option is

> An argument to a command that is generally used to specify changes in the utility's default behavior.

Options that do not take an *option argument* may be written together with the following option as a single argument, i.e. `-i -s -w 40` may be written as `-isw 40`. The command `ls -i -s -w 40 /usr` would have had five arguments.

An option argument is

> A parameter that follows certain options. In some cases an option-argument is included within the same argument string as the option-in most cases it is the next argument.

So, `-w 40` could have been written `-w40`, in which case the command would have been `ls -isw40 /usr` with only two separate arguments.

An operand is

> An argument to a command that is generally used as an object supplying information to a utility necessary to complete its processing. Operands generally follow the options in a command line.

The definitions here are from [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html).

Note also that the following could be true, if the `ls` utility had totally different semantics:
`sw` could have been an option argument to the `-i` option (or `w` could have been an option argument to `-s`) and both `40` and `/usr` could have been operands.